# thymeleaf multi string replace

Tags: string, thymeleaf

I want to do a string replace on multiple keywords:

```
<td th:text="${#strings.arrayReplace(strLocation,['Latitude: ', 'Longitude: '], ['',''])}"></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

I think you want `multipleReplace` not `arrayReplace`. But just in case, I have shown both methods below.

---

**Longer Answer**

*Using `arrayReplace`:*

You can see the method signature of the `arrayReplace` method [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Strings.html#arrayReplace-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

> `public String[] arrayReplace(Object[] target, String before, String after)`

So, an example of how to use that is as follows:

```java
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
// arrayReplace example:
String[] targetArray = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford"};
model.put("targetArray", targetArray);
model.put("before", "Ford");
model.put("after", "Mazda");
```

And the related Thymeleaf:

```html
#strings.arrayReplace(targetArray, before, after)
```

This replaces all occurrences of `Ford` with `Mazda` in the array.

A demo (I wrap the array output in `arrayJoin`, so you can actually see the data in your HTML:

```html
<div th:text="${#strings.arrayJoin(targetArray, ', ')}"></div>
<br>
<div th:text="${#strings.arrayJoin(#strings.arrayReplace(targetArray, before, after), ', ')}"></div>
```

---

*Using `multipleReplace`:*

However, I don't think this is what you want. I think you want to take a string such as this:

```
Latitude: 1.23456, Longitude: 2.34567
```

and convert it to this:

```
1.23456, 2.34567
```

To do that, you can use [`multipleReplace`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Strings.html#multipleReplace-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-):

The Java test data:

```java
// multipleReplace example:
String targetString = "Latitude: 1.23456, Longitude: 2.34567";
String[] beforeArray = {"Latitude: ", "Longitude: "};
String[] afterArray = {"", ""};
model.put("targetString", targetString);
model.put("beforeArray", beforeArray);
model.put("afterArray", afterArray);
```

The Thymeleaf:

```html
<!-- multipleReplace -->
<div th:text="${targetString}"></div>
<br>
<div th:text="${#strings.multipleReplace(targetString, beforeArray, afterArray)}"></div>
```

The resulting HTML, showing the "before" and "after" strings:

```html
<div>Latitude: 1.23456, Longitude: 2.34567</div>
<br>
<div>1.23456, 2.34567</div>
```